# Community - Flow Lookup Component Not Working

Tags: community, visual-workflow, lookup, automation, screen-flow

I am currently setting up a Salesforce Community page, and I need to allow the users to edit details for their Account record or any Account record linked to their Account.

Due to the limited nature of Sharing Sets, I am using a Screen Flow which allows the user to input values for the fields they need to edit, and then updates the record.

One of these fields is a Lookup field, which references a Contact record. I have added the Lookup component into the flow, and ensured that the Source Field Name and Source Object values are correct. However, when the Community user attempts to find a record in the Lookup field, it first says "Search undefined" in the box:

[image]

Then, when they try to search for a Contact, no results come up.

Does anyone know why this would be happening? These are the troubleshooting steps I've taken:

- Ensured the Source Field Name and Source Object values are correct (Source Field Name = Operations_Contact__c, Source Object = Account)
- Ensured that records exist which fulfil the lookup filter for the field (There are two records which should be showing up - confirmed in Salesforce)
- Ensured the user can view Contact records
- Given the user Create permissions on the Contact and Account object (This shouldn't even matter because I've set up the flow to run in System Context - so all access restrictions should be bypassed)

I've run out of ideas here and can't find anything useful online. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `Search undefined` error in the flow lookup inputs are caused by the lookup fields not being on the sObject's page layouts.

In your case, you will need to add that look up field to every single page layout (of the source object) that is assigned to your community user profile.

From Salesforce help page:

> if the lookup field defined in Field API Name isn’t on an assigned page layout. To display the correct text, add the defined lookup field to **ALL** of the source object’s page layouts that are assigned to running users.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_lookup.htm&type=5